# Wait without blocking thread? - How?

Tags: multithreading, f#

This is probably one of the most elementary things in F#, but I've just realized I've got no idea what's going on behind the sceens.

```
let testMe() = 
    async { printfn "before!"
            do! myAsyncFunction() // Waits without blocking thread
            printfn "after!" }

testMe |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

What's happening at `do! myAsyncFunction()`? I'm aware of that it waits for `myAsyncFunction` to finish, before moving on. But how can it do that, without blocking the thread?

My best guess is that everything after `do! myAsyncFunction()` is passed along as a continuation, which gets executed on the same thread `myAsyncFunction()` was scheduled on, once `myAsyncFunction()` has finished executing.. but then again, that's just a guess.

Comment: Your guess is right, although I think the continuation will be run on the next available thread from the thread pool, not necessarily the same thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out, the `myAsyncFunction` is passed a continuation and it calls it to resume the rest of the asynchronous workflow when it completes.

You can understand it better by looking at the desugared version of the code:

```
let testMe() =  
  async.Delay(fun () ->  
    printfn "before!" 
    async.Bind(myAsyncFunction(), fun () ->
        printfn "after!" 
        async.Zero()))
```

They key thing is that the asynchronous workflow created by `myAsyncFunction` is given to the `Bind` operation that starts it and gives it the second argument (a continuation) as a function to call when the workflow completes. If you simplify a lot, then an asynchronous workflow could be defined like this:

```
type MyAsync<'T> = (('T -> unit) * (exn -> unit)) -> unit
```

So, an asynchronous workflow is just a function that takes some continuations as argument. When it gets the continuations, it does something (i.e. create a timer or start I/O) and then it eventually calls these continuations. The question "On which thread are the continuations called?" is an interesting one - in a simple model, it depends on the `MyAsync` that you're starting - it may decide to run them anywhere it wants (i.e. `Async.SwithcToNewThread` runs them on a new thread). The F# library includes some additional handling that makes GUI programming using workflows easier.

Your example uses `Async.RunImmediate`, which blocks the current thread, but you could also use `Async.Start`, which just starts the workflow and ignores the result when it is produced. The implementation of `Async.Start` could look like this:

```
let Start (async:MyAsync<unit>) = async (ignore, ignore)
```